# Using a rails helper in haml, passing a hash causes syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, haml

I get a syntax error for one of my `haml` pages on my rails app:

```
...users/show.html.haml:6: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' ...true_false(( nav_big { profile: @user, art: root_url, storie... ... ^
```

excerpt of show.html.haml:

```
= nav_big { profile: @user,
            art: root_url,
            stories: root_url,
            universes: root_url,
            elements: root_url }
```

I'm trying to pass a hash to my helper and produce a navigation.

excerpt of my navigation helper:

```
def nav_big(items)
    items.each do |key, value|
      items_html += link_to(glyphenize(key), value, class: value == request.original_url ? "active" : "")
    end
    content_tag(:nav, items_html.html_safe, class: "big")
end
```

This is my first time using `haml` and I decided to make my code more DRY by using a nifty helper as I was changing my pages to `haml`.

What is causing this syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to replace the curly brackets with the regular ones in your helper, try this:
    `= nav_big( profile: @user, art: root_url, stories: root_url, universes: root_url, elements: root_url )`
if you prefer the curly brackets then you should use this format
    `= nav_big { :profile => @user, :art => root_url, :stories => root_url, :universes => root_url, :elements => root_url }`

Comment: I'm still getting errors but they're no longer syntax. So I believe it has been solved, thanks. I thought hashes were meant to be instantiated only using curly brackets.

Comment: I'm kind of new to this but I think the curly brackets is the older syntax for hashes in Ruby though still both of them are valid, if I'm not mistaken Rails developers prefer the regular brackets.

Comment: To be honest though, I closed the space between `nav_big` and `(` to make it work.